# What happens to the output of a service?

Tags: debian, systemd, logs, services, daemon

When I run a service from a terminal it shows many logs/errors/successes in output. But if I run it with same command options as a service (under systemd on Debian Linux) it does not show any terminal window or any output. So where does that logs go? Is it redirected to `/dev/null`?

Comment: This question is far too broad to answer without it stating the operating system, and indeed (for some operating systems) the choice of service management subsystem.  Is it Solaris?  AIX?  void Linux?

Comment: That's a kernel.  You need to state the _operating system_, and for several Linux-based operating systems you need to further state the specific choice of service management tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the `systemctl show --property=StandardOutput your.service` command to see where the standard output of your service goes. The usual default is the systemd journal. You can dump the journal with the `journalctl` command (which has the `--unit` option to filter the output by service, but which is [unreliable](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913) for short lived services). There is an analogous `StandardError` service property as well.

Comment: Thanks for that option. I learned detailed explanation from [FreeDesktop: systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).